# Can we make reliable models to estimate what the angular momentum was in preplanetary stellar disks?

Tags: planetary-formation

I have recently become aware of how important the angular momentum of a preplanetary disc may have been in determining what type of a planetary system a star may have. We are able to measure the spin rate of many stars (to what error factor I'm not sure). I'm wondering if, through modelling, we can estimate what disc angular momentum may have been based on remaining angular momentum in the star. Have we looked at systems where we have found multiple planets and also have a good idea of the spin rate of the star to see if there are any correlations?

Comment: I'm curious: How do you categorize the different planetary systems and which distinction do see where the angular momentum of the protoplanetary disk makes a difference? (Without finding further references, other properties like magnetic moment, density / mass, accretion rate, stellar mass might play a bigger role)

Comment: I read a couple of articles like this one. It seems that how fast a protoplanetary disk is spinning may determine the growth of gas giants and then angular momentum transfer determines the final state of the system. As far as classifying planetary system, I get it. They are so diverse that this seem futile, but it's the way our brains work. Some classifications could be systems with A) One outer gas giant and interior terrestrial B) Several outer gas giants and interior terrestrial C) One interior gas giant and no interior terrestrial or other giants D) Interior gas giant with other planets.